# How do I read path like react-router for a conditional-className?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change my footer's className based on the path, like React-Router supposedly does internally.  Either I need to (a) create a state in parent(app) where router is from path in switch then pass it, or (b) read path in child(footer) and put it inline in className ternary directly

Thanks

Comment: Those both sound like viable solutions. Have you tried either one, and if so, what issues are you having?

Comment: Good to know they would work, not sure how to do either. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n MainFooter.js is in UIConainers/Icons

Comment: (b) Does path="/*" work outside of <route />? (a) what is the best way to inherit state from parent (in conditional like this.props.state(currentstate)) + make state from paths?  I think b would be quicker... thanks

Comment: I know I need to use <Link><img className="history.location.pathname === "/Path" ? className1 : "/Path2" : className2 : className3 /></Link> after passing location to child with Links from a <Router> outside the <routes> by <Router location={location} /> or (idk) <Router location={{ pathname: "" }} />
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md
@JakeWorth idk if u get notif

Comment: This question is too broad for me to be helpful. I'd suggest reading up on React props, ternary operators, the `window.location` object, and the classnames library: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

Comment: I started accessing window.location directly but first through the History module, found out the hard way that location.pathname only shows when the user uses back, forward, or enters the url again (Root file rerenders?) : not for changes to (browsingHistory?) state managed by the React Router & Links.
History npm docs (https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#properties).
I'm now assuming since window.location.pathname only works for first url, that I should try to make a state ternary for the Child Footer component wrapped in Links; without somehow grabbing location.state, which I'd prefer

Comment: The 5th comment is incorrect, nested ternary requires input parameter twice window.location.pathname  === "/chats"
                ? "chats_large2"
                : window.location.pathname === "/events"
                ? "chats_large2"
                : "chats_large"

Answer (score 0):

Edit: window.location.pathname works (I must have done something wrong as before it only gave the url when root is refreshed) for conditional className: had to use window.location.pathname for every "/page" check.

```
className={
              window.location.pathname === "/chats"
                ? "chats_large2"
                : window.location.pathname === "/events"
                ? "chats_large2"
                : "chats_large"
            }
```

I could have also done creating in the same div or img onClick={this.handleClick} and

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { page: "" };
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ page: "/chats" });
  };
  handleClick2 = () => {
    this.setState({ page: "/planner" });
  };
```

in the class component above render.

I also put a `<Route render={location => (<Link to=""><div></div></Link>)}/>` around my footer icons, to make the footer rerender when Router goes to a new state and window.location.pathname can read the latest state (which again sometimes it reads the latest render as path, not necessarily the latest Router state).